# How to access mvc controller in web api controller to get pdf from view

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created Web Api and MVC combined for single page web app. I want to call web api and render mvc controller to create pdf from view using Rotativa api. Problem is when i access mvc controller in web api it's not work.

How i access mvc controller in web api to get pdf from view?

**Note:** mvc controller object declared in web api so it gives "ControllerContext" is null in "GetPdfBytesFormView" method.

**Web Api:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/reports/TestReport")]
public class TestReportController : ApiController
{     
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetRequistionPdf")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetRequistionPdf(modelClass oModel)  
    {       
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
        ReportController _Report = new ReportController();
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(_Report.GetPdfBytesFormView(oModel));       
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");            
        return response;
    }
}
```

**MVC Controller:**

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult GenerateReport(modelClass oModel)
    {
        return View(oModel);
    }

    public byte[] GetPdfBytesFormView(modelClass oModel)
    {            
        var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("GenerateReport", oModel) 
        {                
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PageMargins = { Left = 6, Right = 7 }
        };

        byte[] applicationPDFData = actionPDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);            
        return applicationPDFData;
    }
}
```

**Angularjs web api call**

```
$http.post('http://localhost:54527/api/reports/TestReport/GetRequistionPdf', { data }, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                .success(function (data) {
                    var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    window.open(fileURL);
                });
```

Comment: What does "it's not work" mean?  In *what way* does this fail?

Comment: @David, mvc controller object declared in web api so it gives "ControllerContext" is null in "GetPdfBytesFormView" method.

Comment: which would be correct as the context was not set when you declared it. The framework normally handles all of this for you when you call the controller but as you are doing this manually it is not set.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Finally get solution.

Let say your controller name is "PDFController" and action name is "GetPDF". Write following code in your api controller

```
    // Add key value    
    RouteData route = new RouteData();
    route.Values.Add("action", "GetPDF"); // ActionName
    route.Values.Add("controller", "PDF"); // Controller Name
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext newContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), route, controller);
    controller.ControllerContext = newContext;
    controller.GetPDF();
```

Your are done now. Your pdf should get generated.

Hope it help

Comment: But, who is "controller" in the last 2 lines ?

Comment: Object of controller in which your method GetPDF exist i.e.  PdfController controller = new PdfController(

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing your GetRequestionPdf with below one:

```
public HttpResponse GetRequistionPdf(modelClass oModel)  
    {       
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        ReportController _Report = new ReportController();

                response.Clear()
                response.ClearContent()
                response.ClearHeaders()
                response.Buffer = True
                response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=xyz.pdf")
                response.BinaryWrite(_Report.GetPdfBytesFormView(oModel));
                response.End()


        return response;
    }
```