# ASP.NET Rotativa Generate PDF from view from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I have two controllers, 1 is an api controller, the other is a view controller, what I am trying to do is generate the PDF from the api controller from a view in the view controller...is this possible and how would I do it?

API Controller - This is where I want to generate the PDF

```
public byte[] getReportsPDF(string community, string procedure)
{
            byte[] pdfBytes = new byte[] { };

            System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext();

            if(procedure == "GetProductionTasks")
            {
                var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("RedBluePDF", new { community = community, procedure = procedure })
            {
                    PageSize = Size.A4,
                    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
                    PageMargins = { Left = 1, Right = 1 }
                };
                pdfBytes = actionPDF.BuildFile(context);
            }

            return pdfBytes;
}
```

View Controller - This is the view I want to generate.

```
public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure)
{
    return View();            
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should not call API controller from View controller. What you can do is have a separate PDF generation class and Invoke the PDF generate from both View and API controller. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699884/calling-web-api-from-mvc-controller)

Comment: Hey I’m trying to call a view controller from API controller

Comment: If you isolate the GeneratePDF  method, you can then call it from the api.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262064/how-to-access-mvc-controller-in-web-api-controller-to-get-pdf-from-view?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

After trying for a very long time, finally I managed to solve by this:

```
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ViewController>();
RouteData route = new RouteData();
route.Values.Add("action", "RedBluePDF");
route.Values.Add("controller", "ApiController");
ControllerContext newContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), route, controller);

controller.ControllerContext = newContext;
controller.RedBluePDF(community, procedure);
```

I have been trying:

```
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ControllerB>();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.Request.RequestContext, controller);
```

But this will give me the wrong pdf, because it will use your current controller (API Controller in this case) to make the call for `ActionAsPdf()`

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40521592/8570735)